# Can I get 2 value in Option Value in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can I get 2 values in option value in jQuery?

example :

```html
<select name="example" id="example">
   <option value="2000">Cloth</option>
   <option value="3000">Hat</option>
   <option value="4000">Shoes</option>
</select>
```

I must grab "2000" And Cloth or another option, because `$('#example')` return just "2000" please help.

Comment: Are you asking how to get the string "cloth" or how to enable selection of 2 items????

Comment: you cant get 2 or more then 2 selected untill you use `multiple` in select
 option

Comment: what do mean by `get two values`  ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$('#example option:selected').text()` to get the text and use

`$('#example').val()` to get the selected value.

Comment: `$('#selectorId option:selected').val()`  would be better i guess

Comment: this answer is perfect if user wants value + text of selected option

Comment: I am not sure why I got minus vote on this answer. :)